# Facebook Like-button comment box event subscribe

Tags: events, comments, facebook-like

Long story short;
I have facebook Like-button on my website with comment box enabled.
I need to refresh current page every time user clicks like button (likes or unlikes my content).
I can achieve this with `event.subscribe` and `edge.create / edge.remove` events but the problem is that user should be able to post comments with like-clicks, too.

Currently this works fine with like-clicks only but the `edge.create / edge.remove` event executes in a few seconds after user has clicked like button and therefor not giving user enough time to write her comment in the comments box and post it.

I've tried `comment.create` and `comment.remove` events, but they're not firing at all when the comment is posted and because of that the page just won't refresh at all.

So the problem is;
Does anyone know how I can execute page refresh when user posts comment with like-click via the comment box that is integrated with like-button?

Any help would be appreciated! Thanks!

Comment: To be more precise: I need to refresh current page after the user has clicked Like-button AND posted comment via Like-buttons comment box-feature.

Comment: In case anyone is wondering the same - there currently isn't any (reliable) way to do this. Like-button doesn't have any events for integrated comment box. I used a few dirty hacks to achieve what I wanted but can't say it's the best way to go.

Answer (score 0):

After struggling with this same problem for a while, and not being able to find a solution, I decided to go another approach.

While I see value in the Comments Box, I also see it as not very good design to have a Comments Box appear seconds before the page redirects/refreshes. So... with a little CSS you can hide the Comments Box, which might be a good option for you until Facebook makes Subscribing to a Like Comment Post, or Close of the Comments Box.

```
.fb_edge_comment_widget {
  display: none !important;
}
```